# MySQL access on Google cloud LAMP stack

Tags: mysql, cloud

I have just installed the LAMP stack on Google cloud which includes php and mySQL. I have managed to setup php properly and also connect to PhpMyAdmin using the ip/phpmyadmin link. I logged in to phpMyAdmin and created a database and then I tried importing the data that I exported from another database, again using PhpMyAdmin. The problem is that PhpMyAdmin takes hours and does not finish - I have to stop and restart the VM instance, otherwise PhpMyAdmin does not respond. Since I am new to this, I am not sure if there is anything else I need to do in order to be able to use the MySQL database. Do I need to create an SQL instance from the Google Cloud console? Isn't the LAMP stack supposed to do this for us?

Answer (score 0):

There must be something wrong with the import function on PhpMyAdmin. I ended up executing inidividual SQLs in PhpMyAdmin for creating the tables and importing data and it worked without problems - execution time also took less than 1 second, even for inserting 500 records.